# Atom NameError: name '' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I am writing a simple team picker program and I keep getting this error message:

```
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

My code works in online python interpreters so i am not sure if is my code or the text editor that i am using which is atom.

Screenshot of my code:

[image]

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code in the question?

Comment: `while add_players.lower() == 'y':` `lower` is a function, not precomputed argument

Comment: use ```add_players = input("would you like to add another player")``` in the while loop

Comment: You have a `y` somewhere in your code that isn't enclosed in quotes, which causes the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a reminder: since code is text, it is preferable to include it in the question as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work

```
players = []

while input('Would you like to add players to your team? Y/N').lower() == 'y':
    name = input('What is the players name?')
    players.append(name)

print(f'You have {len(players)} players on your team')
```

You need to call `lower` (like `lower()`) to actually get the lowercase answer, not the function `lower`. Also I moved the add player input to the while loop to make it more clean.

Comment: Hi @AhmedHachimi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.